# PostgreSQL datatype for public key?

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes, public-key

What PostgreSQL datatype should we use for a table column that stores public keys?

Should we store it as text base64-encoded (in the format that the application server receives it from the client), or should the application server convert it to data and have the database store it as a blob?

Comment: I'm not sure if you get any advantage in saving it to blob over text. What's your concern?..

Comment: OK. Thank you. I guess my concern is to do what's standard/best practice, and performance. I'm not concerned about security or privacy because they're *public* keys.

Comment: i'd store as type text

Answer (score 1):

I would say store them as `bytea` type.

Public keys are actually a binary blob that has been base64 encoded when exported using the `armor` option.